# How to copyWith list items on Bloc[Flutter]

Tags: flutter, bloc

I want to change List<Map<String, dynamic>> list on Bloc.

Below is my sample bloc code.

Please teach me how to use copyWith correctly.

[Sample Code]

```
class StateA extends Equatable {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap;

  StateA({ required this.listMap});

  StateA copyWith(
   {List<Map<String, dynamic>>? listMap,}) {
  return StateA(
    listMap: listMap ?? this.listMap);
}
}

class CubitA extends Cubit<StateA> {
 CubitA() : super(StateA(listMap: []));

 void testCopy() {
  emit(state.copyWith(listMap: [{"test_key": "test_value"}]));
  print(state.listMap); // => []
}
```

(I'm not good at English, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

I solve it to add object?.

The code is below.

```
class StateA extends Equatable {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap;

  StateA({ required this.listMap});

  StateA copyWith(
   {List<Map<String, dynamic>>? listMap,}) {
  return StateA(
    listMap: listMap ?? this.listMap);
  };

  // Add below code
  List<Object?> get props => [listMap];
}

class CubitA extends Cubit<StateA> {
 CubitA() : super(StateA(listMap: []));

 void testCopy() {
  emit(state.copyWith(listMap: [{"test_key": "test_value"}]));
  print(state.listMap); // => [{"test_key": "test_value"}]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

So the copy with function in this context should be used to add maps to the list of maps.

```
StateA copyWith(
   {List<Map<String, dynamic>> newListMap}) {
  return StateA(
    listMap: [listMap, newListMap]);
}
```

This function will allow you to add items to the current state's listMap and emit a new state.

Suggestions:

1. Don't make the the copyWith function's parameter as an optional parameter (remove the question mark).
2. You'll have to override the props function for equatable to work. Refer to the docs or some video to get an understanding of that.
3. If you're very new to flutter ignore this.. but I'd recommend going through the freezed class videos to make bloc state. I'll link a video below. It generates all the boilerplate code for copyWith and equality operations.
   https://youtu.be/ApvMmTrBaFI

Comment: If you have anymore questions, just let me know I'll answer them.

Comment: Thank you! I will learn your Suggestions!

Comment: Had a mistake in the copyWith function, corrected it, you can have a look once again.

Answer (score 1):

this working

Bloc state:

```
enum ProductStatus { initial, loading, success, failure }

class ProductState extends Equatable {
  const ProductState(
      {this.status, this.error, this.productResponse, this.categoryResponse});

  final ProductStatus? status;
  final String? error;
  final ProductResponse? productResponse;
  final CategoryResponse? categoryResponse;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status, error, productResponse, categoryResponse];

  ProductState copyWith({
    ProductStatus? status,
    String? error,
    ProductResponse? productResponse,
    CategoryResponse? categoryResponse,
  }) {
    return ProductState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      error: error ?? this.error,
      productResponse: productResponse ?? this.productResponse,
      categoryResponse: categoryResponse ?? this.categoryResponse,
    );
  }
}
```

Emit like this:

```
 CategoryResponse categoryResponse =
          CategoryResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(result.response.toString()));
      emit(state.copyWith(
          categoryResponse: categoryResponse));
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a object for your **StateA** and then access the copywith through that object.

Comment: Thank you. I just add the object? and I could solve this question.